# Print list without line numbers in R

Tags: r

I would like to print a list in R without line numbers.

I tried the `cat` command but it doesn't work for lists.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

```
    GROUP    SEX INCOME STATE    n  mean
11       1   Male      1    AL  159 26.49
12       2 Female      1    AL  204 26.64
13       3   Male      2    AL  255 27.97
14       4 Female      2    AL  476 29.06
```

Example data to use:

```
foo <- structure(list(GROUP = 1:4, 
                      SEX = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L),
                                      .Label = c("Female", "Male"),
                                      class = "factor"),
                      INCOME = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                      STATE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AL", 
                                        class = "factor"), 
                      n = c(159L, 204L, 255L, 476L), 
                      mean = c(26.49, 26.64, 27.97, 29.06)),
                 .Names = c("GROUP", "SEX", "INCOME", "STATE", "n", "mean"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = 11:14)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of you code or what you are trying to display?

Comment: Whilst we are waiting, and to clarify matters, what you show is (or looks like) a data frame, not a list. Is it the `11, 12, 13, 14` that you don't want printing? Also, to help out the [so] crowd, could you include the output of `dput(foo)` in your question, after the example data?, where `foo` is the R object you pasted in? That will give something concrete to work with.

Comment: @GavinSimpson For privacy with this particular data set I'd rather not print out the whole data set. Will use dput in the future though

Comment: @pmagunia I meant just for the snippet you showed. For example, if your object is `foo` and you want only the first 4 rows, then `dput(foo[1:4, ])` would help. As it happens I did it for you by reading the four lines into R, changing the rownames, and `dput()` it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Do you just want the argument `row.names = FALSE`? E.g.

```
> print(foo, row.names = FALSE)
 GROUP    SEX INCOME STATE   n  mean
     1   Male      1    AL 159 26.49
     2 Female      1    AL 204 26.64
     3   Male      2    AL 255 27.97
     4 Female      2    AL 476 29.06
```

where this is using the `?print.data.frame` method.

Comment: Good one, did not know about that option :) Much better than my solution

Comment: This is alot easier than working with regular expressions ! Thank you

Comment: @pmagunia That said, I suspect writing the data frame to file/connection and then piping through awk, it would be very easy to remove the row names, depending on the context. The `printed` representation of the table may not be what is wanted in all contexts. But glad you found the Answer helpful in this case.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, what do you do in case of list of lists like : `C=list(listA = list(1:3, structure(1:9, .Dim = c(3L, 3L)), 4:9), 
    listB = list(c("t1", "t2", "t3"), structure(c("p1", "p2"), .Dim = 2:1)))`, in this case `print(C,row.names=FALSE)` does not work !

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
apply(l, 1, function(x){cat(x); cat("\n")})
```

Comment: This `apply(l, 1, function(x){cat(x, sep = '\t'); cat("\n")})` could work (prints `.tsv` formated table).